# Align <nav> content to the left side the flexbox row rather than the right?

Tags: html, css

How can I align the nav items, Page One and Page Two so that they present to the left rather than to the right?  I can move the content center and to the end, but I simply need to move the two nav items to the left and the flexbox option don't seem to allow me to do so?  Please help, thank you.

```css
#box1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#list1 {
  display: flex;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.list2 {
  list-style-type: none;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="list1">
  <nav>
    <ul class="list2">
      <li>Page One</li>
      <li><a href="page2.html">Page Two</a></li>
    </ul>

  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: can you clarify ? nav is not a flex box and **page item** are standing on the left. *main* and *#box1* are not there either  What's the question ?

Comment: I'm brand new to HTML/CSS.  In a nut shell, when the Page One and Page Two display, I would like to move them over to the left so they are right up against the left margin.

Comment: do you mean you need something alike :`ul, li{margin:0;padding:0;}`?

Comment: Yes, thank you.  Thought I had removed the margin on the body so didn't think it was a margin issue.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If mean to have the `nav` anchors to be aligned left to each other you can simply add [`flex-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Legacy) the li elements if you mean to flex on nav:

```css
.list2 { 
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.list2 li {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="list1">
  <nav >
    <ul class="list2">
    <li>Page One</li>
    <li><a href="page2.html">Page Two</a></li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

---

or you can also use `inline-block` on `<li>` elements like in this snippet:

```css
.list2 li {
  display:  inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="list1">
  <nav >
    <ul class="list2">
    <li>Page One</li>
    <li><a href="page2.html">Page Two</a></li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```